# Selenium C# getting text from this kind of structure

Tags: c#, selenium

```
   <div id = "productInformation">
   "This is a sample text: " <a>this is a sample link value</a>
   "This is a sample title: " <a>this is a sample link title</a>
   "This is a sample type: This is an information about the type." 
   "Page: 888"
   </div>
```

What I am trying to do is getting the value of Page. Is there any built in     method or way to do this in selenium without digging into some hard coding or may I do hard code to get the data? Any suggestions would be appreciated?

I'm using xpath.

Comment: Means do you want to get only int value as 888 or something else??

Comment: actually i have multiple data to collect in projectInformation div. but it has no elements for each data inside the element div that has an id of projectInformation so I cannot do any xpaths on the values. here are the data i want to scrape. Page, Category and Print type. any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Here is a more clear overview of the structure.
http://screencast.com/t/RxyFcXgdA

Data that i need to scrape are Pages, Category and Bindings.
Values are Dynamic. @SaurabhGaur

Comment: Can you show what is ur expected output ??

Comment: @MohitShrivastava http://screencast.com/t/RxyFcXgdA check this. my expected output should be. 

Pages: 192
Category: Education, Nonfiction, 
Binding: Paperback (Revised)

Comment: It is not enclosed in a special tag, therefore selenium alone cannot handle it. I would use Regex to get the value from the whole text.

Comment: Maybe you could ask the developer to include <span> elements. This would make your life easier.